# Docker command COPY doesn't copy updated files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

my goal is to work on a project using docker without having to constantly rebuild my whole project each time I modify a file a little bit:
The file bellow (not complete) has 2 state, an already updated version that I will call
**Version_0** which looks like this :

```
<#modelInf> rdf:type ja:InfModel ;
#    ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:/fuseki/ontologies/server_famille.ttl> ; ] ;
    ja:reasoner   [
        ja:reasonerClass    "openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory" ; ]
  .
```

Once updated it works well, but then I decide to uncomment one line, this file I will call **Version_1** :

```
<#modelInf> rdf:type ja:InfModel ;
    ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:/fuseki/ontologies/server_famille.ttl> ; ] ;
    ja:reasoner   [
        ja:reasonerClass    "openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory" ; ]
  .
```

The important part of my dockerfile looks like that :

```js
FROM [...]

RUN mkdir -p /fuseki
RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/configuration/
WORKDIR /fuseki

COPY server/configuration/db_tdb.ttl configuration
```

I also run a docker-compose file [Edited]

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  jena-fuseki-server:
    hostname: jena-fuseki
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    environment:
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - FUSEKI_DATASET_1=ds
    command: cat /fuseki/configuration/db_tdb.ttl
```

The issue seems to be that the first time I run `$docker-compose up --build` it works well and copy **Version_0** right, after modification, I rerun `$docker-compose up --build` and I expect **Version_1**  to be the file copied. what happens is that, after verification navigating my image thanks to `docker exec -it [name] bash` and executing `cat db_tdb.ttl`, it still shows me **Version_0**. Testing my app confirm me that **Version_0** is the one running.
[Edited] The `cat` command I added shows me that **Version_0** is the one copied aswell

> What have you tried ?

- The command `docker-compose build --no-cache` followed by `docker-compose up`
  result: didn't work and doesn't accomplish what I want.
- The command `docker system prune -a` followed by `docker-compose up --build`
  result: it did work but doesn't accomplish what I want.
- I also tried to target the configuration folder instead of the file itself
  result: no noticeable changes.
- Adding a `RUN rm -f configuration`
  result: no noticeable changes
- [Edited] Run : `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate`
  result : no noticeable changes

> Honorable mentions

- During my project, I did not always have this issue.
- When I use `docker-compose up --build` it uses the cache except for the modified file yet still doesn't work

Since it is a big project, I can't resolve myself to run `docker system prune -a` or using `--no-cache` as it would result in a HUGE lost of time.
I feel like it worked at some point but I can't understand the reason nor give it consistancy.
Thanks you.

Comment: Have you tried with `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate`?

Comment: That doesn't look like a complete compose file. Are there volumes? Can you provide a [mcve] that doesn't depend on files that are not included in the question?

Comment: Can you try `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up --build`? I used to get this issue if I didn't stop my previous container. Or you can `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up` if you need low downtime

Comment: @BMitch @DianelCampos I edited my question aswell as tried ```docker-compose up --build --force-recreate``` without success, I have no volume. I marked as ```[Edited]``` everything  I changed. Thank you.

Comment: @NanoBit Doing : ```docker-compose down``` followed by ```docker-compose up --build``` seems to have resolved my issue, I still don't undestand why would the ```--force-recreate``` flag not work  
Thank you !

Comment: @Hahiro, glad to hear that it worked

Comment: @NanoBit can you post it as an answer so I can accept it and it can be usefull for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `docker-compose down` followed by `docker-compose up --build`.

It seems that removing the container first fixes some hidden cache problems.